# Nginx: can't access my server using the hostname

Tags: linux, nginx

I have two remote nginx servers. One of them has stopped responding when I try to access it using it's hostname. It works fine if I use the IP address instead.

Things I've tried to no avail:

- Restarting nginx. Status says it's running.
- Checked the config files with `configtest` and contrasted them between both servers and everything seems to be fine.

**PING**

If I `ping` the IP I always get a response

```
64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.353 ms
```

If I `ping` the hostname, I only get a response if I executed the ping from the server machine's shell:

```
64 bytes from my.host.name (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
```

From any other machine I get:

```
ping: my.host.name: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

**NSLOOKUP**

`nslookup my.host.name` returns SERVFAIL

```
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 8.8.8.8, trying next server
Server:         8.8.4.4
Address:        8.8.4.4#53
** server can't find my.host.name: SERVFAIL
```

However, a reverse nslookup `nslookup xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` returns  the hostname

```
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53
Non-authoritative answer:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa     name = my.host.name.
```

**NETSTAT**

- If I run `netstat -napl | grep 443` on the server that works fine I get:

  ```
  unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     514944439 7128/named
  ```

  On the server that gives me issues I get no result.
- If I run `netstat -tulpen | grep 80` I get:

On the good Server:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          480010417  11588/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          480010415  11588/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          480010413  11588/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          514850980  12554/pure-ftpd (SE
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          480010418  11588/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          480010416  11588/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          480010414  11588/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      112        514988015  30356/mysqld
udp6       0      0 fe80::ff:fe60:4a9:123   :::*                                0          14307      946/ntpd
```

On the bad Server:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          468245733  32249/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          468245731  32249/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          468245729  32249/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1972            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          373088058  7701/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          373013803  27069/pure-ftpd (SE
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          468245734  32249/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          468245732  32249/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          468245730  32249/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::1972                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          373088060  7701/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          373013804  27069/pure-ftpd (SE
udp6       0      0 fe80::ff:fe63:1407:123  :::*                                0          13917      555/ntpd
```

Bad Server:

Comment: You netstat command returns something because of `514944439`. This has nothing to do with nginx. Try `netstat -tulpen | grep 443`.

Comment: @Lenniey that won't return anything on either server

Comment: Then nothing is listening on 443. Do you use HTTPS at all? Try `netstat -tulpen | grep 80` or `netstat -tulpen | grep nginx`

Comment: @Lenniey afaik I only use HTTP. I edited my question with the output

Comment: So your server is up and running. Is the IP/hostname being resolved correctly?

Comment: @Lenniey how can I check that? If I ping the IP I always get the response. If I ping the hostname (www.sample.hostname), I only get the response if I executed the ping in the server's shell, otherwise, from any other machine I get `www.sample.hostname: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's public you probably have problem with your domain registration. Check your DNS registrar information. This has nothing to do with your nginx server.

Answer (score 1):

Is the hostname working before the problem happened or this is a new setup?

Have you check the following? 
 1. Is your nameserver function properly? 
 2. Does your server allow port 53 for DNS?

Comment: Yes, it was working fine until a couple of days ago, I've no clue what happened but suddenly I couldn't reach my site. It uses nginx, honestly I've no idea how to the nameserver is handled or if it's working, I couldn' t find that answer on the web. How/where can I check if port 53 is allowed?

Comment: Enter your hostname in https://mxtoolbox.com/dnscheck.aspx. Does it show your server ip?

Comment: Can you show the output of this command on both your server and client you used to ping the server? "cat /etc/resolv.conf".

Comment: @VitautsStočka no, it does not

Comment: @teclinux both output the same two lines: `nameserver 8.8.8.8` `nameserver 8.8.4.4`

Comment: Is your servers public or running locally? If locally then the two nameservers won't help in resolving the hostname.

Comment: @teclinux it's public

Comment: Since it is public, then you should contact the support of your domain name hosting company, see if anything wrong with their nameserver. If you're using A Record, then check the A Record to see if it uses your latest IP address of your server. Probably your server (I assume it is a VPS) somehow has its IP changed? This is possible if you're using dynamic IP for the VPS, where it changed if your VPS  restarted (for whatever reason).